# How do I use the output of a function as the input for another function inside a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments

I am currently studying Python and hoping someone could help me.
I'm fairly new to coding so would be really helpful if its explained well.

Lets say I have a function called `function1` that returns:

```
return (row, column)
```

Now I am writing another function called say `function2`.
Within this function I need to call say:

```
exampleItem.exampleName(row, column, name)
```

How do I use the output of the `function1` which is the row and column as the `row` and `column` arguments in the above line from `function2`?

I really hope this makes sense as I got seriously penalized for not writing a question properly before because I didn't realize the best practice here.

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.2 I believe. Have now solved the issue though thanks to this great community :D

Comment: Hey Gazza, if one of the answers solved your question you can always mark one as accepted by clicking on the check mark besides the answer, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Also, I've edited your question to format some things and trim-off the EDIT that specifies what you decided to use. This is common practice on Stack Overflow, people see your question and then scroll down to the answers to see possible solutions, no need to explain what you did if it exists as an answer :-)

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't realize. Also, I'm having issue with using tuples now. I'm using Python 3.5.2 and I heard something about it not supporting them but I'm not entirely sure how to put it and I don't want to be penalized for putting a question incorrectly again. Do you have any advice on what to do sorry? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can always ask a *new* question where you describe the problem, provide code that reproduces it and explains what you want it to do. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the star `*` to unpack the result --*which is a tuple*-- of  calling function `function1` after you place it as an argument inside the other function. This results in providing the elements returned from `function1` as positional arguments in the second:

```
exampleItem.exampleName(*function1(), name)
```

In Python `2.x` you can do the same but, you *need* to supply the *remaining* positional arguments in keyword form in order to get it to work with `*`:

```
exampleItem.exampleName(*function1(), name=name)
```

this also works on Python 3.x so you have no issues with portability.

Of course, unpacking in a previous statement with `row, column = function1()` and then providing them to the second function by position with:

```
exampleItem.exampleName(row, column, name)
```

is another option. It really falls down to preference in the end :-)

Comment: Prefer the last example. If the interface of either method changes it would mean a more difficult debugging job than if everything were explicit.

Answer (score 7):

In all versions of Python you can do:

```
row, column = function1()
exampleName(row, column, name)
```

In more recent versions (`3.5+`) you can use unpacking to do things like:

```
exampleName(*function1(), name)
```

For further reading see: [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 2):

This is called "tuple unpacking", which takes the parts of a tuple (or list) and uses them as arguments.

If `f1(row, column)` is the function returning `(row, column)` (for the sake of a simple example):

```
a = f1(3, 4)
b = exampleItem.exampleName(*a, name="fish")

# Or, as a one-liner:
b = exampleItem.exampleName(*f1(3,4), name="fish")
```

The major limitation here is that after the tuple-unpacked argument (`a` above, you unpack with a `*`), all further arguments must be assigned by name, not position.

If you can't give specific argument names, and if you're still using Python 2, you'd need to do something like:

```
x, y = f1(3, 4) # unpacks the length-2 tuple into two variables
b = exampleItem.exampleName(x, y, "fish")
```

Which cannot be made into a one-liner. Python 3 doesn't require that, though, so you could do the first example without needing to use `name=` on the third argument if you're in Python 3.

Another relevant note: If you use `**` instead, you can unpack a dictionary, which does the same thing as tuple unpacking except for named arguments instead of positional arguments.